# SQL + Javascript - Multiple fields into something I can loop through?

Tags: javascript, sql

I have two fields I need to pull data from in SQL and put that into an array or list that I can loop through. Then for each loop, I do something based on both the fields for each index. What is the best method for this? I thought maybe a dictionary or possibly creating an object?

Right now I pull the fields into two seperate arrays,  and I loop through both at the same time, but I am finding that sometimes one array has a blank value, and then they get out of sync and I have issues. This seems like a terrible implementation anyway.

How can I put these into a key value pair and then act on the data?

Edit: I should note that my SQL code just returns a bunch of comma seperated values. So it was easy to create an array out of those, but its proving more difficult to create anything else such as an object because I get all the values at one time.. :(

```
 var equipIDArray = //SQL Gathering code here
 var equipTypeArray = //SQL gathering code here

for(var cnt = 0; cnt < equipIDArray.length; cnt++){
      alert(cnt);
      if(isNaN(equipIDArray[cnt]) === true){
         equipIDArray[cnt] = '';
      }

  switch(equipTypeArray[cnt]){

  case 'Blower' : 
     alert('test1');
     break;

  case 'Dehumidifier' : 
     alert('test2');
     break;

  default : 
     alert('default');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It' easy to translate your arrays into an object if they just represent key/value pairs. Then you have an object you can use like a dictionary:

```js
var equipIDArray = ["Blower","Humidifier","Lawn Mower"];
var equipTypeArray = ["Leaf blower","Whole House Humidifier","Honda Brand"];
var equipment = {};

for(var i = 0; i < equipIDArray.length; i++) {
  equipment[equipIDArray[i]] = equipTypeArray[i];
}

for(property in equipment) {
  console.log(property + " : " + equipment[property]);
  alert(property + " : " + equipment[property]);
}
```

Comment: Edited answer to accommodate translation of arrays of keys/values into object.